# How i can compare models in template

Tags: django, foreign-keys

Why this compare code not work? I want to display all departments where departments filial = filial, but i got failure only. Thanks very much for you answers!

```
{% for filial in filials %}
        {{ filial }}
        {% for dep in departments %}
            {{ dep }}
            {% if  dep.Filial == filial.pk %}
                IFIFIFIFIF{{ dep.fullname }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
```

models:

```
class Filials(models.Model):
    Fullname=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=False)
    Entity=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    City=models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=True)
    INN = models.IntegerField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Fullname
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/{self.id}'

class Department(models.Model):
    Filial=models.ForeignKey(Filials, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='department', blank=True)
    Fullname = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Fullname
```

Comment: `dep.Filial` is an object, use `dep.Filial_id` to use the ID on the `dep` object.

Comment: Don't compare this in the template, the template should *not* implement business logic.

Comment: You can get the relevant `Department`s with `{% for dep in filial.department.all %}`, and thus drop the `{% if ... %}` condition.

Comment: Guys, you are best. Thanks you! @WillemVanOnsem i take you solution for my problem, its working!